# jetty9.3.5 websocket Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketServerFactory.init()V

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-websocket, jetty-9

Can you help me resolve this error?

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketServerFactory.init()V
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TFM9.png)

Comment: Please copy and paste code instead of linking an image: it lets people edit your code to help solve, is easier to search and read, and doesn't link rot.

Comment: Please give more detail about what you were doing or trying to do when you encountered this error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to use Jetty 9.3+ with Spring Framework < 4.2.

Compatibility with Jetty 9.3+ has been introduced with Spring Framework 4.2 and [SPR-13140](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13140).

Please upgrade your Spring version to fix this problem.